# XML-parsing in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

If I have a XML-document like this

```
<Doc>
   <File>
      <ObjectID></ObjectID>
   </File>
</Doc>
```

And it sometimes can look like this

```
<Doc>
   <Name />
   <File>
      <ObjectID></ObjectID>
   </File>
</Doc>
```

How can I get the `File`-elements? 
They are not always on the same level, sometimes they can be on the root-level 
There could also be times, when it is placed multiple times in the Document (but then they are at the same level)

**UPDATE**

The `<File>`-element can also have `<File>` elements below, which should not be parsed like this

```
<Doc>
   <Name />
   <File>
      <ObjectID></ObjectID>
      <RelatedTo>
         <File></File>
      </RelatedTo>
   </File>
</Doc>
```

In which case the result should be

```
<File>
   <ObjectID></ObjectID>
   <RelatedTo>
      <File></File>
   </RelatedTo>
</File>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `s` being the string which contains your XML code:

```
var document = XDocument.Parse(s);
var fileElements = document.Descendants("File").
                       ToArray();
```

Note that you won't get one single element but an array. In case there's only one in your document, then the array will have just one element.

The above approach will work even if the `File` elements are children of other elements, but I'm not sure what you meant by them being at "root level". Isn't that the case that you brought us?

**EDIT:** To adapt it to the author's edit:

```
var elementName = "File";
var firstFileElement = document.Descendants(elementName).
    First();
var fileElements = firstFileElement.Parent.Elements(elementName).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: No, in the example `<Doc>` is at the root-level

Comment: @The87Boy Ah, when you said "*they can be placed on the root-level*" I thought that you meant multiple roots, which is clearly badly formed XML. Either way, the above approach will work even if the document's root is a `File` element.

Comment: Thanks, it was the XName that was confusing me

Comment: Does it take care of upper- and lowercase?

Comment: @The87Boy No, because XML is case sensitive. The query can be rewritten by using a `Where` statement instead of passing the `elementName` to `Descendants` and `Elements`.

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Maybe I have another question, but I will of course create another question if it comes