# Web service that parses XML data for Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, windows-8

I am trying to create a windows 8 app that will allow my users to create records in gridview and when prompted will allow them to send them to a database and then allow them to modify/delete them.

I wanted to use XML to accomplish this, so when the user creates a record it will output to an xml file then send to the sql database.

I know I will need to use a web service to accomplish this and after doing research I found out that using SOAP will be my best option but I am totally new at trying to do this so not sure where to begin.

Any guidance on how to go about this or reference material to get me started would really be amazing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to start with these links:

[Accessing WCF Services with a Windows Store Client App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[XML Parsing in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297947/xml-parsing-in-winrt)

[SQL Server Through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)